Are most true statements about Math unprovable (undecidable)?
In an essay titled: All Questions Answered, Donald Knuth states that “In fact, we now know that in some sense almost all correct statements about mathematics are unprovable.” How do we know that?
I’m guessing this is a diagonalization argument, similar to the Turing thesis, which I am familiar with. I get how the set of mathematical proofs is countably infinite. But why is the set of true mathematical statement non-countable? In so far as a true statement must be written down in some formalism, then isn’t it countably infinite.

Gödel's work, as well as the axiom of choice,  might be relevant.   Also whether you are working in ZFC, and axiomatic (or naive) set theory.
